# Proper way of adding stuff to senchas carousell in runtime

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, carousel

So how can I add stuff to carousell in sencha touch 2.x?

```
var c = Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
            fullscreen: true,

            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },

            items: [
                {
                    html : 'Item 1'
                }]
        });
```

If I want to, for example, push a `form f` to the carousell how can I do that?
I have already tried `c.push(f)` and `c.add(f)` but I can't see my form being added there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of adding stuff into a container like `Ext.Carousel` is using the `add()` function. You can also define your carousel like this, if you want to just add all your stuff to it in runtime:

```
var c = Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
            fullscreen: true,

            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            }

            });
```

Now you can use the `c.add(f)` function. Also to remove the object `f` from the carousel or other container `c` use `c.remove(f)`